# Build list of prefixes, including the whole string

Tags: javascript, performance

There is a string "abcdebfkj", we need to transform this string to the below array:

expected o/p:

```
["a", "a.b", "a.b.c", "a.b.c.d", "a.b.c.d.e", "a.b.c.d.e.b", "a.b.c.d.e.b.f", "a.b.c.d.e.b.f.k", "a.b.c.d.e.b.f.k.j"]
```

I am able to do that, but was looking for more promising solution if any. I did that in O(n) time complexity. Please let me know if the below can be improved in any way.

```js
function splitString(str) {
  const result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  i === 0 ? result.push(str[i]) : result.push(`${result[i-1]}.${str[i]}`);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(splitString("abcdebfkj"))
```

How can I avoid checking the index and make the `for` loop work?

Comment: Can't be \$O(n)\$. The result itself is \$O(n^2)\$, and you cannot build it faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am able to do that, but was looking for more promising solution if any. I did that in O(n) time complexity.

It's not quite clear what you mean by "more promising". But it should be obvious that it can't be done in better than O(str.length<sup>2</sup>) steps and space.

> How can I avoid checking the index and make the `for` loop work?

The best way to avoid checking the index and make the `for` loop work is to not use the index and not use a `for` loop. There are plenty of very powerful iteration methods on [`Array.prototype`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-properties-of-the-array-prototype-object) like [`Array.prototype.map`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.map) or [`Array.prototype.join`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.join), and most importantly [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.reduce). In fact, there is a nifty little sketch of a proof on the Wikipedia page for [*Fold*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)#Universality) (which is the computer science name for `reduce`), which shows that `reduce` can do everything a loop can do. There's also [`Array.from`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.from), which is really powerful.

Now that I have praised all of the powerful methods, I have a confession to make: the problem you have is actually a [*Prefix sum*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum) which can be perfectly solved with the `scan` function. But … unfortunately, that specific method is missing from `Array.prototype`.

If `scan` *did* exist, the solution would look something like this [I'll add a simplistic implementation of `scan` just to make it run]:

```js
Array.prototype.scan = 
  function scan(f, z) {
    return this.reduce(
      (acc, el) => acc.concat([f(acc[acc.length - 1], el)]),
      [z]
    );
  }

function splitString(str) {
  return Array.from(str.substring(1)).
    scan(
      (a, b) => `${a}.${b}`,
      str.charAt(0)
    );
}

console.log(splitString("abcdebfkj"));
```

[Here you can see it in action in the programming language [Scala](https://scala-lang.org/), which does have `scan` in its standard library: [https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JoergWMittag/lGpk4P66SZOovCV5o6jt1Q/19]](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/JoergWMittag/lGpk4P66SZOovCV5o6jt1Q/19%5D)

Unfortunately, without `scan`, we have to do a bit more work.

```js
function splitString(str) {
  return Array.from(
    { length: str.length },
    (_, i) =>
      Array.from(
        str.substring(0, i + 1)
      ).
        join(".")
  );
}

console.log(splitString("abcdebfkj"));
```

The outer `Array.from` creates an `Array` of length `str.length`, and it uses the return value of the arrow function as each element.

The arrow function gets the current index as its argument, it uses the [`String.prototype.substring`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-string.prototype.substring) method to grab the first `i` characters of the string, converts that substring into an array of characters using the above-mentioned very versatile `Array.from`, and then `join`s the characters back together with a `"."`.

We can try and more directly re-implement `scan`:

```js
function splitString(str) {
  return Array.from(str.substring(1)).
    reduce(
      (acc, c) => acc.concat([`${acc.slice(-1)}.${c}`]),
      [str.charAt(0)]
    );
}

console.log(splitString("abcdebfkj"));
```

This is essentially an inlined version of the above solution using `scan` and the simple definition of `scan`.

So, the main trick is to use the methods that ECMAScript provides us, in particular the ones provided on `Array` and `Array.prototype`.

Comment: Don't you think reduce method is designed to make an array to single value? Just clarifying things. Your code works superb and I really understand every piece of it. Also, we are making two array one is from `Array.from` and another one for `acc` which take more memory?

Comment: "Don't you think reduce method is designed to make an array to single value?" – Yes, that's what `reduce` does: apply a binary operation between all elements of a collection to reduce the collection to a single value. In my case, the single value just happens to be an array itself. There's nothing in the type signature of `reduce` that forbids that.

Answer (score 2):

I am not into JavaScript anymore, but:

```
function splitString(str) {
  const result = [];
  var o = "";
  for (let ch of str) {
    result.push(o + ch);
    o += ch + '.';
  }
  return result;
}

function splitString(str) {
  const result = [];
  var o = "";
  Array.fromString(str).forEach(ch => {
    result.push(o + ch);
    o += ch + '.';
  });
  return result;
}

function splitString(str) {
  const result = [];
  var o = "";
  for (let ch of str) {
    result.push(o + ch);
    o = ch + '.';
  }
  return result;
}
```

Another variable remains, but the backtick evaluation becomes senceless.

Your requirement is fulfilled by:

```
function splitString(str) {
  let result = str.split(''); // Array with letters
  //let result = Array.fromString(str); // Array with letters
  for (let i = 1; i < str.length; ++i) {
    result[i] = result[i-1] + '.' + result[i];
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: If you run this code it doesn't return the expected results, but the last one works well.

Comment: You are right, corrected, though I intended to let `o` contain the pushed value.